# Dagger hilt android where to add retrofit

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I am not expert of android nor kotlin and we are discussing in team about dagger hilt. We are using retrofit and not sure where we should inject it. All examples shows that we should inject retrofit inside SingletonComponent that means it is globally accessible and we want to avoid using singletons in general only if we really need it. Maybe I am completely wrong with thinking but how would you do this actually and what decision you use when making something to be accessible on Application level ?

Comment: Have you created a custom Module class also for that?

Comment: If you did not mark the Retrofit object as Sigltone then for every API call new Retrofit object gets created, So create a Module class and Provide one instance of a retrofit from that class